# Get the text value of an input element in C#

Tags: c#, html, selenium, text, input

I want to read the text next to an input item with C#.

This is my HTML:

```
<p id="mpNames">
  <input id="selectMp1" type="checkbox">
  "Text next to the input element"
```

This is my code:

```
var inputWeList = drv.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#mpNames > input"));
foreach (var inputItem in inputWeList)
{
       var inputItemText = inputItem.GetAttribute("value");  // gives "on"
       ...
}
```

My second try:

```
var inputWeList = drv.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#mpNames > input"));
foreach (var inputItem in inputWeList)
{
       var inputItemText = inputItem.Text();  // gives ""
       ...
}
```

How do I get "Text next to the input element"?

Comment: Can you show more HTML around that text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the text `"Text next to the input element"` is out of the `<input>` tag. So instead of :

```
var inputWeList = drv.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#mpNames > input"));
```

You can try :

```
var inputWeList = drv.FindElements(By.XPath("//p[@id='mpNames' and not(@type='checkbox')]"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `inputItem.InnerHtml` or `inputItem.innerText` instead for `GetAttribute("value");`  and `.Text()`, Here is the difference between both:

> Unlike innerText, though, innerHTML lets you work with HTML rich text
>   and doesn't automatically encode and decode text. In other words,
>   innerText retrieves and sets the content of the tag as plain text,
>   whereas innerHTML retrieves and sets the same content but in HTML
>   format

Comment: But also inputItem.GetAttribute("innerHTML"); gives me "".

Comment: @kame Have you tried the property, `inputItem.InnerHtml` instead for method `GetAttribute`

Comment: I can't use `inputItem.InnerHtml` in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get them by JavaScript because the text are under the same parent. JavaScript need to walk through child nodes of the `< id="mpNames"` and returns all child nodes which are text nodes.   See my example below.

```
var script = @"function getTextNode(rootNode) {
    var nodes = rootNode.childNodes;
    var fieldNames = [];
    var count=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if ((nodes[i].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)) {            
                let text = nodes[i].textContent.trim();
                fieldNames[count++] = text;                   
        }
    }
    return fieldNames;
}";

var results = (drv as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript(script) as List<string>;
results.ForEach(txt => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(txt));
```